# 3d coverflow in Open GL

Tags: opengl-es, coverflow

Is there any coverflow control(commercial/free) available on Web which is developed in Open GL ES?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

take a look at PowerVR SDK - it has an example of coverflow implementation just in pure OpenGLES.